# Use Looped Array to take in DataSheet Values

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE, java and selenium webdriver. 
I have a webform that I want to loop thru multiple times using unique values each time.  The values will come from an .xlsx file.  For the 1st iteration, value will come from column 1, row 1.  2nd iteration, value will come from column 1, row 2, etc..
My question is - is it possible to write the code to allow the next value to be taken in each time?

Below is what I have tried - to create an array to hold the location of the values.

```
for (int Count = 5; Count <=10; Count++)    {

Utility.ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Utility.Constant.Path_TestData + Utility.Constant.File_SellerNetwork30,"Sheet1");
String[] sStoreNumbers = {Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData};
sStoreNumbers[0] = Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 1);
sStoreNumbers[1] = Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(2, 1);
sStoreNumbers[2] = Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(3, 1);
SellerNetworkSetupPage.txt_StoreNum(driver).sendKeys(sStoreNumbers);
SellerNetworkSetupPage.btn_Add(driver).click();

if (Count ==10) {
break;}
```

This only works for the first one.  The 2nd and 3rd Strings throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1     at   StoreOptionsPage.StoreOptions_SellerNetworkCreate30TEST.mymaintest(StoreOptio    ns_SellerNetworkCreate30TEST.java:94)     at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to fix/improve this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an index out of bound exception because the array sStoreNumbers is only populated with one element therefore the array's length is 1 and the index positon of the element is 0. You trying to store data in index positions 1 and 2 which are out of bounds. You should modif your code as follows:

```
for (int Count = 5; Count <=10; Count++)    {

Utility.ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Utility.Constant.Path_TestData + Utility.Constant.File_SellerNetwork30,"Sheet1");
String[] sStoreNumbers = new String[3];// modification to code is here.
sStoreNumbers[0] = Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 1);
sStoreNumbers[1] = Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(2, 1);
sStoreNumbers[2] = Utility.ExcelUtils.getCellData(3, 1);
SellerNetworkSetupPage.txt_StoreNum(driver).sendKeys(sStoreNumbers);
SellerNetworkSetupPage.btn_Add(driver).click();

if (Count ==10) {
break;}
```

Comment: Look for the comment in the code in my answer that is where the modification is. Please up vote my answer if you think it is worthy.

Comment: ah, ok that worked great!

With that fix, now the webform is taking in all values from the array at once.  I only want one value to be taken in at once.  How can I do that?
Flow should be:
.sendKeys(1,1)
.click
repeat - use next value (2,1), etc..

Comment: You should use counters for that. Please accept and up vote my posted answer if it helped you.